i have this error in pentoo , Cannot import gnuradio
I have Pentoo and I use GNU Radio but after a couple days, I deal with this error.
I just remember yesterday I want to install GNU Radio packages, for write my code.
Cannot import gnuradio.
Is the Python path environment variable set correctly?
All OS: PYTHONPATH
Is the library path environment variable set correctly?
Linux: LD LIBRARY_PATH
Windows: PAΤΗ
See https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/ModuleNotFoundError
(/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so.6: version
CXXABI_1.3.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/
gnuradio/gr/gr_python.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so))

